# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+a^n )z^n$ for $a \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+a^n )z^n$ for $a \in \mathbb C$

Here is what I think it should be

$$R=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac {n+a^n}{n+1+a^{n+1}}\right|$$

Since $a \in \mathbb C$ so there exist an $p$ and $\alpha$ such that $a=pe^{i\alpha}$,so

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac {n+p^n e^{in\alpha}}{n+1+p^{n+1}e^{i(n+1)\alpha}}\right|$$

From here I feel like I can apply the L'Hospital rule, but when I do it, it just goes on forever. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hint : $$\sum (n+a^n)z^n=\sum (n)z^n+\sum (az)^n$$  find radius for each one ,then find common radius

Comment: what do you mean by the common radius? One of them has radius $1$ and the other has radius $\frac{e^{i\alpha}}{p}$ (I don't want to use $1/a$ because $a$ can be zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simpler to use the root formula: $\dfrac{1}{R} = \limsup \sqrt[n]{|n + a^n|}$. If $|a| > 1$ this is just $|a|$. Otherwise it is $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why $|a|>1$ yield $|a|$?

Comment: If $|a| > 1$ and if $n$ is sufficiently large you will have $n \le |a^n|$, and thus $\sqrt[n]{|n + a^n|} \le |a| \sqrt[n]{2}$.

Comment: Since $\frac{n}{a^n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to{0}} $ for $|a|>1.$

Comment: $$\sum nz^n\rightarrow  |z|<1\\\sum a^nz^n=\sum(az)^n \rightarrow  |az|<1 $$for example a=3 $$\sum 3^nz^n\rightarrow  |3z|<1 \rightarrow  |z|<\frac{1}{3},|z|<1 \rightarrow |z|<1/3$$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash so the common radius from your example is just $1/3$? That's it?